# $GVIMRC not getting set

Tags: vim

I am running on Lubuntu 14.10.

From my bash shell (these all have 777 permissions):

```
ls -a ~ | grep -i vim
.gvimrc
.vim
.vimrc
```

From vim, when invoking from my bash terminal emulator:

```
:echo $HOME
/home/jonbri

:echo $MYVIMRC
/home/jonbri/.vimrc

:echo $MYGVIMRC
```

For some reason my $MYGVIMRC variable isn't getting set.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Because you are running vim, not gvim ? Also, those files *probably* don't need 777 permissions.

Comment: Ah, I see...it's only available when running gvim. That makes sense and I confirmed you are right. If you expand this into an answer I will mark it accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.gvimrc` (or `_gvimrc`) file is only sourced when the GUI is initialized (either from running gvim, vim -g, `:gui` and possibly other methods I don't know of).
 Since `$MYGVIMRC` is only set when `.gvimrc` is sourced, it isn't set when using (terminal) vim.

From `:help gui-init` (some parts removed, emphasis mine) :

> When the GUI starts up initializations are carried out, in this order:
>
> - The 'term' option is set <...>
> - If the system menu file exists, it is sourced. <...>
> - If the "-U {gvimrc}" command-line option <...>
> - For Unix and MS-Windows, if **the system gvimrc exists, it is sourced**. <...>
> - The following are tried, and only the first one that exists is used:
>
>   - If the GVIMINIT environment variable exists <...>
>   - If **the user gvimrc file exists, it is sourced**. <...>
>   - For Win32, when $HOME is not set, "$VIM_gvimrc" is used.
>   - When a "_gvimrc" file is not found, ".gvimrc" is tried too.  And vice
>       versa. <...>
>
>   The name of the **first file found is stored in $MYGVIMRC**, unless it
>     was   already set.